# need to send data on url onLocationChanged method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

i need to send data on url onLocationChanges method,m trying to accomplish the task with following code,but m getting error,can someone help me out?
My program crash with following code

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) throws NetworkOnMainThreadException {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address_textview);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ",         Longitude:"         +         location.getLongitude());

String strUrl="http://www.test.com/location.php?location="+location.getLatitude();
try {
    url = new URL(strUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConnection.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

Comment: [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NetworkOnMainThreadException)

Comment: I would suggest to click on the previous comment. Declaring that your method throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is going to help you absolutely zilch. The answers to the plethora of questions on this specific exception should more than suffice.

Comment: Why throws NetworkOnMainThreadException? you should make sure that cant happen instead of throwing it, make the request on a separate thread.

Comment: Can u guys please explain.. Actually I m a Web developer and new to Android environment..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do network I/O in `onLocationChanged()`. You'll need to start a background `Thread` in `onLocationChanged()`. The background `Thread` can then do the network I/O.

Answer (score 0):

you can write following code on your MainActivity.java class's onCreate()

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: This is not a good idea in this case. Network I/O can take a long long time (socket timeouts and DNS timeouts are minutes long). In this case you can block the main (UI) thread for way too long. It is never a good idea to do network I/O on the main thread. OP should be doing network I/O on a background thread.